# Objective-C array insert into mysql using json

Tags: sql, objective-c, arrays, json

I am creating an application that the user presses a button and every time they press the button, it adds a record in the array. I need to get this data into a external mysql database, the best method seems to be through php using JSON.

How do I convert my array into a JSON array? and what does the php code look like for inserting the array into the database?

Comment: I have been worked in several project connecting my iOS app with webservices using this example. http://divcode.blogspot.com/2012/08/connecting-to-php-service-from-ios.html It's the more easy way to do this. Hope it help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/downloads) library to convert

```
NSArray -> NSString
```

Import `SBJson.h` in your .m file and use following code

```
NSString *jsonString = [array JSONRepresentation];
```

You can implement php code using [this](http://divcode.blogspot.com/2012/08/connecting-to-php-service-from-ios.html) tutorial.

**Edit**

As suggested by **RobP**, you can use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert `NSArray` to `NSString`

```
NSError *error; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionaryOrArray 
                                               options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                 error:&error];

if (!jsonData) 
{
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} 
else 
{
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: SBJson can be a hassle depending on whether you use ARC or not, 64-it or not... since iOS5 there's the NSJSONSerialization class built in, when I moved to that it made our code smaller and more mainatainable.